# Linux : how to grant different access to sudo session based on original user

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

This is might be unusal question, but please bear with me!

**Background**: I am using Redhat Linux server to host my java application. there are 3 users (non root)

**app_user** that runs application processes and process controller.

**adm_user** that has sudo access to app_user to do administration of app (starting stopping, configuring etc).

**op_user** this is supposed to be operator user who should have limited access to application admin functions such as start, stop & clean logs.

Application has menu based command line utility to do all the activities, and each menu item has one or more shell scripts behind it to run selected command.

I can grant sudo to op_user and present with limited menu but nothing is preventing op_user from directly accessing shell script and running the commands.

**Question** : Is it possible to both users (adm_user and op_user) to sudo to app_user but based on logname (their original identity) restrict/grant access to files/folders?

**Note :** One option I explored is to create list of commands **op_user** can run, but maintaining/predicting that list in advance is not sustainable.

Thanks

Comment: IDK if this helps but you can customize sudo by editing the ```/etc/sudoers``` file giving different permissions to different people. For example, adding ```exampleuser    ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nano``` would allow example user to run ```sudo``` without a password.  I am not aware of anything restricting file access.

Comment: Thanks Todd, actually I am trying to have 2 user sudo to same account but  have different set of permissions based on original user.

Comment: Why not dispense with sudo and simply `chmod u+s` the application binary so it runs as app_user (assuming that is the most powerful user). It can then check with `getuid()` who is running it and restrict what it allows the user to do.  (Of course, you cannot setuid java, so you will need to write a small C program that execs the java command with all parameters set, absolute filenames, and nothing taken from the environment, and setuid the C binary.)

Comment: @meuh Thanks, yes that would work, just my IT security guys (correctly so)  don't like setuid part of it.

Comment: `sudo` can not only set a user id but also a group id, so you could have sudo set the same id but separate groups for adm and op, and try restricting files by group ownership and id/group/other permissions.